# How to discover which is the protocol in the 802.11 body frame?

Tags: networking, network-programming, packet, libpcap, wifi

I would like to know how to discover which is the network protocol in the 802.11 body frame, I mean, for example, the ethernet frame has the field "type", but in the 802.11 standard and I didn't find any field to show me which is the protocol.

Comment: [wireshark](http://wireshark.org/)

Comment: In fact I am writing a software, so I can't use Wireshark to do that, I need do discover the protocol using C language.

Comment: Then we need to see some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to look at [the type field in the 802.11 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Layer_2_.E2.80.93_Datagrams).  There are three frame types - [Management frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Management_Frames), [Control frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Control_Frames), and [Data frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Data_Frames).

For Data frames, the 802.11 header is followed by an [802.2 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.2), which contains a Destination Service Access Point (DSAP) that can specify the protocol running atop 802.11+802.2.  If the DSAP and Source Service Access Point, or SSAP are both 0xAA, the 802.2 header is followed by a [Subnetwork Access Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork_Access_Protocol) (SNAP) header, which contains an IEEE [Organizationally Unique Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_Unique_Identifier) (OUI) field and a "protocol ID" (PID) field.  The interpretation of the PID field depends on the value of the OUI field; if the OUI is 00:00:00, the PID field is an Ethernet type field, otherwise it's a value specified by the organization to which the OUI refers.